# What are the forces acting on an air particle along curved streamline(wing upper surface)?

Tags: aerodynamics

What forces act at air particle at curved streamline (at first 1/4 upper wing surface) , looking from inertial and non-inertial frame of reference? (show free body diagram)

[image]
Pressure gradient normal to the local flow direction balance the centrifugal force associated with the curvature of flow..
**Which Centrifugal force,inertial or reactive?**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there a specific problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: no i just ask in general..just looking from physics perspective

Comment: We have a [PhysicsSE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) that is a great place for physics questions.

Comment: Inertial and non-inertial reference frame? Interaction forces are independent of reference frame and inertial forces are only dependent on the reference frame.

Comment: Jan can you write your answer?

Comment: @AeronauticFreek forces you are looking for are not applicable to air particles, but to any dust particle. air particle moves in all directions, not only in the average movement and direction of air particles. See [this question on physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/492013/85763) for more information.

Comment: @Jan Hudec,centripetal force at this particle cause radial pressure gradient,but what is with centrifugal force.can you explain inertial centrifugal force vs reactive centrifugal force  for this praticle,what is difference with these two forces and how they fit in each frame of reference?

Comment: @Jan Hudec, .How do you mean there is no such thing?.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_centrifugal_force.. i also first time heard for these term 2 days before..

Comment: @AeronauticFreek, well, this terminology is confusing and often used slightly differently. Anyway, the centripetal force is the force on the astronaut from the shell. It is an interaction force, independent of reference frame. There is a reaction to it, acting *on the shell*, that you may call reactive centrifugal force. That is also interaction force, so also independent of reference frame. This is balanced by the ‘centripetal’ stress in the shell. In the non-rotating frame, only force on the astronaut is the centripetal one, so he rotates. …

Comment: … In the rotating frame, there is a centrifugal force on *everything* that fixes it so the astronaut is in place.

Comment: @ManuH. It is better to clarify that in this kind of mathematical analysis an "air particle" is treated as a sufficiently large volume that thermal molecular motion may be ignored, yet sufficiently compact as to appear arbitrarily small at the macroscopic scale.

Comment: @Aeronautic Freek if you are looking for balance of forces, you must have steady state.  This can be found in *balance of the 4 forces* of the entire aircraft.  Most simply put, the force of the air moving downwards (thus the reactive force of the plane upwards) = weight, the force of drag from this activity = thrust.

Comment: @GuyInchbald That's exactly why it should not be named "air particle" (e.g. a pressure can only be defined on a volume containing at least one particle).  I propose to name it "a small volume of air" or "a dust in the air streamline" or any other non-ambiguous term.

Comment: @ManuH Then you had better tell NASA. Their glossary at https://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/K-12/aerosim/LessonHS97/GLOSSARY.html defines a streamline as "A line depicting the flow path of a particle of air."

Comment: @GuyInchbald Done. I'm waiting for there answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the inertial frame of the free airstream, the pressure force causes the particle to accelerate inwards. Centrifugal and centripetal forces do not play a direct role; there is no space station wall for centrifugal force to be exerted on, nor to exert a reactive centripetal force. The pressure force acts in the role of the centripetal force shown in the astronaut diagrams. The balancing reactive force is instead another pressure force, which acts on the airfoil where it is known as lift.

In the rotating frame of the air particle, inertial centrifugal force does come into play. The particle must by definition remain stationary within its reference frame, so all forces on it must now balance. The pressure force is thus balanced by the inertial centrifugal force. The airfoil lift no longer plays a direct role within this reference frame (having helped to create it).

Comment: Your first paragraph is perfect, the wing is pulled into its own low pressure area as well (also creating induced drag).  It concerns me that the OP even worries about "balanced centrifugal force".  On what, a tiny nanomite along for the ride on the air molecule? +2 for "where it is known as lift".

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni As I noted in a comment to the main question, it is trivial to clarify that in this kind of mathematical analysis an "air particle" is treated as a sufficiently large volume that thermal molecular motion may be ignored, yet sufficiently compact as to appear arbitrarily small at the macroscopic scale.

Answer (score 0):

> can you write your answer?

Air flow striking the wing is deflected either up or down as the wing literally slices through the air.  This can be looked at as either the air hitting the wing (wind tunnel) or the wing hitting the air (actual flight).  Relatively, between air and wing, the effects are the same.

The bottom airflow is rather mundane, slowing and creating higher pressure under the wing, eventually leaving the higher pressure zone either downward, to the rear, or out the side (to form a vortex).

The top particle, pictured, has a more interesting time.  It is deflected upwards not by the wing, but the zone of higher pressure in front of the wing.  Logic would suggest that this pushes the wing *down*, so what happens next?  How do we get lift?

The trick is to shape the wing in such a way, and pitch it at such an angle, to have that particle drawn backwards and **downwards for a greater distance than it was pushed up**, resulting in *net* positive lift.

Within a certain Reynolds number range, positive pitch and camber create a zone of low pressure above the wing, which can be only maintained within a range of velocity and angle of attack.  If this is done correctly, our particle will be *accelerated by pressure differential as it tries to fill the void*.

A lifting wing at adequate airspeed will pass by the particle before it reaches the wing, repeating the same process with the next particle over and over again. When returning to its original position, relative to the wing chord, the **original particle is** where the **wing was**.

Its momentum will continue its movement below the wing with its fellow particles, creating "downwash".

Comment: I didnt mean on this..I mean to show free body diagram at this particle..centripetal force=radial pressure gradient which balance centrifugal force,,also this partcle accelrate so it has inertial force ...etc etc

Comment: If the particle is accelerating, forces are *not* in balance, though you may wish to capture the exact moment it stops moving upwards and begins downward movement.  This will vary, depending on leading edge design and wing camber.  Sort of trivial (they all will, to produce upper wing lift, finishing with more downward *momentum*), but why not have a go at drawing it, and show us what you have so far.

Comment: If you throw a ball up in the air, it is always accelerating downwards, though it's *movement* (velocity) goes to 0 for an instant before it falls.  The *gravity vector force is unbalanced*, drag vector forces would reverse.  Drag and gravity forces would eventually balance to reach steady state only if ball is allowed to reach "terminal velocity".